# ASP.NET - Sending a PDF to the user

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a process that creates a PDF.  I want these PDF's to be temporary and short lived.  I want to be able to perform the following when the user clicks a button:

```
string CreatePDF()//returns fileName.pdf
PromptUserToDownloadPDF()
DeletePDF(fileName.pdf)
```

I want to avoid having to create a cleanup procedure and deal with any race conditions that arise from users concurrently creating PDF's while running cleanup.

In winforms, I would synchronously prompt a user to download a file.  How can I do a similar task in web?

**UPDATE**
Please note that I am using a 3rd party app to create the PDF's ([Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/)).  Basically I (will) have a function that invokes the command line:

> C:>fop "inputfile" "output.pdf"

So, in memory is not an option...that is unless I could somehow do like....

```
string CreatePDF()//returns fileName.pdf
string RecreatePDFInMemory()
DeletePDF(fileName.pdf)
PromptUserToDownloadPDF()
```

Comment: fop does support piping its output to stdout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this:

```
byte[] _pdfbytes = CreatePDF();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", _pdfbytes.Length.ToString());
Response.BinaryWrite(_pdfbytes);
```

Since this creates the PDF in memory, you don't need to worry about cleanup.

**Edit for OP's edit:**

From within `CreatePDF`, You can use [`Path.GetTempFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) to create a temp file and execute "fop" to write to that file.  Delete that file immediately before returning the `byte[]`.  I recommend doing this delete inside of a `finally` block.  However, "Fop" does support having its output piped to stdout.  Having the `CreatePDF` function grab that is probably cleaner.

Comment: If you want to pipe output using standardoutput, see [`Process.StandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx)

Comment: Great answer - You got some serious skills.

Answer (score 2):

Look into doing something along these lines.

Similar to what someone referred to in a different answer, you don't need to save the PDF file on your system, you can just send it as a response.

I'm not sure how you're creating your PDF, but try looking into this below and seeing if your process could use something like this.

```
HttpResponse currentResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response;
currentResponse.Clear();
currentResponse.ClearHeaders();
currentResponse.ContentType = "application/pdf";
currentResponse.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=my.pdf");

//create the "my.pdf" here

currentResponse.Flush();
currentResponse.End();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of your process but you should be able to write the PDF to a byte[] and skip writing to the disk altogether.

```
byte[] pdf = GetPDFBytes(filename)
MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream(pdf);
```

Then use the pdfStream to send back to a user.

Answer (score 0):

You can stream out a file with an asp.net page.

I tried to find very old article for you which demonstrates this with a GIF (there's not an actual file)

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25487

It makes a special page which streams out the data (sets content type appropriately in the header).

Similarly, you can make a "page" to stream out the PDF - it might not even need to ever reside on disk, but if it did, you could delete it after streaming it to the browser.