# why is folder created in server and not local PC

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.net website and in the code behind I am creating a folder on page load, if it doesn't exist in the local drive:

```
string strDirectory = @"C:\PDFGenerate\";
try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(strDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(strDirectory);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ce)
        {
            tc.Text = "Unable to create directory to save generated PDF files";
        }
```

The website is currently hosted in my local server. I added the website to my IIS so I can access it locally from any PC in our network.

The issue I am experiencing is whenever I access the website from my local PC, the folder is being created in the server and not in my PC.

Is this something to do with access? I tried to create a folder in my own local drive and it worked fine.

Comment: Websites can't create folders on the client PC. Imagine what would happen if they could.

Comment: hmmmmm... There is a point. But the website is a locally hosted within our network. What would be the workaround it?

Comment: The app is running on the server. So if you tell it to save something to the c drive, it's going to do exactly that - save it to it's c drive.

Comment: @SiKni8 It doesn't matter - the code still runs on the server.

Comment: Okay now it make sense guys. Thanks. I will resort to JavaScript and see if I can achieve the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: You're not going to have much more luck with JavaScript.  A better idea is to generate the pdf's on the server, then give the user a link to download them to their local machine.  Since its hosted locally, perhaps saving to a shared drive would work as well.

Comment: @paqogomez I will have to find a way to figure that out. Thank you.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? What's the end business goal?

Comment: My goal is the user clicks a button and it generates a PDF form for them to view/download, hence why I was trying to create the folder to save the file to automatically or they can go and view/print whenever they want. But I decided to keep the folder on the server and make it shared and show them the link to download. I wanted to make it local because in case the user doesn't have access to the server, they can still view the PDF at a later time.

Comment: See my answer to [Sending a PDF to the User](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5586842/18192).  When the user clicks "get PDF", run that code in the code-behind.  The call the `CreatePDF` in my answer would need to return a `byte[]` representing the PDF (for larger PDFs, you may need to stream them instead).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The issue I am experiencing is whenever I access the website from my local PC, the folder is being created in the server and not in my PC.

Yes. That's because all your code is being *executed* on the server. The server just delivers HTML to your PC, and the web browser displays the HTML. Of course, if that includes some Javascript, *that* will run on the PC (in the browser) - but the C# runs on the server. (Think about it: how would you expect the C# code to run on a machine which didn't have any facility for running .NET?)

It's really *really* important to understand where your code is running. As a web app creator, you don't get to create folders on client machines. You've got some very *limited* access to local (i.e. client-side) storage, but you won't be able to perform arbitrary file system operations. That would be horribly insecure.

Comment: The OP indicated that the site is running on their own network.  So, he could save the PDF to the user's computer via sharing or similar, if the server has access to the user's machine (e.g., the server could save the file to `\\SiKni8\C$\PDFGenerate`).  Generally I would consider this to be a horrible idea.